# How to implement a live-updating resource on a chat app using Emberjs with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, chat

I already have a pseudo-working chat app using Emberjs on client and Rails on server and data is stored on MySQL.

I thought that since I used ember-rails gem, the server will automatically update the `store` of all users currently online if the server receives a new chat 'message` posted by some user.
But it seems like it only works one-way and not two-way. That is if I post a message on the client, the RESTful adapter also updates the database on the server (I tested this working). However, if I update the database on the server with new messages, it does not automatically update the store of the client or say I open two windows of the page at the same time, then I post a message on one, but the other page doesn't update automatically (I would need to hit f5 or refresh first).

And so, I would like to know if I'm just missing something from Emberjs or Rails that will naturally support this live-syncing feature. I search over the net about this and it seemed that the closest one was this [(link)](http://www.thomasboyt.com/2013/04/13/emberjs-and-firebase.html) - check `EmberFirebaseChat.Message.find())` on that page. But I'm not using firebase.

The other only thing I could think of is for Ember to constantly poll the server and check for new chat messages. Say every 2 seconds, it will request for all current messages from the server. But this doesn't seem very efficient, and looks like a lot of coding I'm unfamiliar with.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This isn't an ember issue in so much as how websites work.  Generally speaking the client has to ask the server for updates.  More recently cool technologies like web sockets let you have bidirectional communication (i.e., your server can push to the client).  If you're using a node.js backend you can look at socket.io and ember-sockets (https://github.com/Wildhoney/EmberSockets).  Otherwise the simplest thing to do is to just poll the server every few seconds from the client.

Comment: Great thanks! I'll check on web sockets :)

Comment: Rails 4 supports this with SSE. You can checkout ActionController::Live, which pushes events to the client from the server: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html